# SQL Server xp_fileExist different results depending on login

Tags: sql-server, windows, permissions, filesystems

I'm creating a stored procedure which needs to check if a file exists. It uses **master.dbo.xp_fileExist** to do this.

Problem is that xp_fileExist results seem to change based on the SQL Server login that I use. It seems to only work when the login has the SYSADMIN server role.

So, if I login using ACCOUNT:ACC1, PASSWORD:PWD1, and ACC1 does not have the SYSADMIN server role, I get the following results:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_fileExist 'adsnt.dll'

File Exists File is a Directory Parent Directory Exists
----------- ------------------- -----------------------
0           0                   0
```

If I then go into SSMS and assign the SYSADMIN role to account ACC1, I get the following results:

```
File Exists File is a Directory Parent Directory Exists
----------- ------------------- -----------------------
1           0                   1
```

I can't seem to find any documentation about this. Most responses to queries of this kind suggest that the login doesn't influence file access, and that instead it depends on the Service Account that SQL Server is running under. But clearly that's not the case (or, at least, it's not the complete story). Does anyone have any idea what's going on here, please?

Comment: `xp_fileExist` itself isn't documented. What does the `sys.dm_os_file_exists` function return? I guess the real question is why you are using SQL Server to do basic file access in the first place. Powershell is much better placed to do this.

Comment: Thank you - `sys.dm_os_file_exists` seems to return the correct result, regardless of whether the login has the SYSADMIN role or not. This helps tremendously. And of course, I agree that Powershell would be superior for normal file access. This is required because the stored procedure needs to read a data file which may not exist. If it does not, the procedure cycles backwards through dates until it finds one (the DLL in the example was just used for testing). Thanks again!

Comment: Note that that is *also* undocumented, use at your own risk. Why do you need it, anyway? Why is a stored procedure reading files? If you need it for an SQL Agent job, you can create one that uses Powershell

Comment: Just edited my comment to include an explanation.

Comment: Long and short of it: there are very few cases when T-SQL should be doing this kind of thing. If necessary, you can get file names in Powershell or C#, Python etc, and pass them into SQL as parameters

Comment: The stored procedure is called by an SSRS report. It reads data from the SQL Server DB but also requires up-to-date data from an XML file that is used for storage by another piece of vendor software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Change this

exec master.dbo.xp_fileExist 'adsnt.dll'

-- To this
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_file_exists ('adsnt.dll')

Should work without the need for SysAdmin role